# Programming C calling function area of circle and rectangle

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PI 3.14159
int Circle (int);
int Rectangle (int, int);
int main()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    int d;
    int area;
    int AreaOfCircle;
    int AreaOfRectangle;
    int area1;


    printf("Program to calculate area\n");
    printf("1 - Circle\n");
    printf("2 - Rectangle\n");
    printf("\n");
    printf("What option = \n");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    if(a=1)
    {
        area=Circle(b);
        printf("Area= %d\n", area);
    }
    else if(a=2)
    {
        area1=Rectangle(c,d);
        printf("Area= %d\n", area1);
    }
    return 0;
}
  int Circle (int b)
  {
    int area;
    printf("radius= \n");
    scanf("%d", &b);
    area=PI*b*b;

    return area;
  }
  int Rectangle(int c, int d)
  {
    int area1;
    printf("length= \n");
    scanf("%d",&c);
    printf("width= \n");
    scanf("%d",&d);
    area1=c*d;

    return area1;
  }
```

//I want to ask if my coding is ok .. but as I run it the output only ask for radius which is the calling function for circle .. but if i want to call rectangle the output also shows calculation for circle .. can someone help me to spot the mistake .. by the way this is my first coding about calling function and I just started learning coding c last month .. T-T

Comment: Hmmm: `int area;.... area=PI*b*b; return area;`  Using integer variables for the area of a circle?  Using floating point, like `double`, will provide a more interesting result.

Answer (score 1):

With C you use == to evaluate (e.g. if (x == 1)). "=" is assignment, so you'll always hit the first block.

Also, you're accepting parameters which you're then modifying, which is not good practice. Consider declaring your variables at usage time also, the "everything at the top of the block" paradigm is very dated.

This question is *not* about functional programming, this is an example of imperative programming.

Also, your input being poured directly into an integer is not bounds checked, consider a switch/case so you can add a default of "invalid input" and extend to different shapes in the future.

Comment: wahh .. it works !! thank you so much .. sorry, I`m still newbie in c programming .. T-T .. I`ll noted your info .. thank you ...

Comment: No problem, that's what we're here for!

Comment: what is the different between functional and imperative programming ??

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming - Probably a bit confusing if you're new to the game though.

Comment: thank you .. it is a bit confusing .. but i`ll try to digest it ... ^_^

Answer (score 0):

Yes bro just make if(a==1) and else if(a==1).

Answer (score 0):

You've used the assignment `=` operator instead of the comparison `==` operator.

A statement like

```
if(a=1)
```

will assign a value of `1` to `a` and check then check for the non-zero value of `a` [which always evaluates to TRUE].

Instead, what you want is

```
if (a == 1)
```

which evaluates to TRUE if `a` contains `1`. Same for other comparison(s) also.

Note: In your `int Circle (int b)` case you're storing the result to an `int`, which will truncate the result of a `double`/`float` multiplication. To get the exact value, make the `area` as `float` or `double` and use `%f`/ `%lf` format specifier.

Next, as per the logical part, you don't need to pass `b`, `c`, `d` as parameters to the called functions. Simply a local variable in the functions  would do the job.

Comment: oh I see ... just a small mistake but i failed to noticed it .. thank you so much ...

Comment: @Adz once you solve the first issue, notice my updated answer. There are other issues, too.

Comment: I`m still learning a lot .. thank you for the more detailed answer .. because i`m still new .. i cant understand what you mean by integer multiplication ??

Comment: @Adz Please refresh the page. I've updated again. :-)

Comment: @Adz Hint: the result of `PI*b*b` is not an `int`.

Comment: i see .. because the area should be in a decimal point so i must use float or double ?? right ???

Comment: @Adz Absolutely. That's the catch. :-)

Comment: oh i see .. haha .. thank you .. i`ll noted your info ... ^_^